# Emacs: How to open new frame on a second screen in windows

Tags: init-file, frames

I use two screens and windows 10, and want to open a new emacs frame on the other screen than the one I use. How do I do this?

Preferably, I want the new frame made to be maximized in size.

I have tried `make-frame-on-display` but this function asks for `display` name that seem not to be defined on my computer.

Comment: Emacs 25 accepts size and placement parameters with pixel specifications:  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/17354/2287  You can use the `make-frame` function with your favorite parameters, and, you can also set up `initial-frame-alist` and `default-frame-alist`.  You can get fancy and identify a particular display, but I've only read about that.  If your other screen is just an extension of the primary screen then top/left coordinates should be all you need to put a frame farther over.

Comment: Here is a semi-related thread where a user queries about identifying which display a particular frame is located.  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14618/determine-whether-a-frame-is-shown-on-primary-display  You may be able to apply some of those concepts to get dimensions and coordinate frame placement. However, it may be simpler to just use top/left frame parameters when creating the frame if you can programmatically determine where one display ends and the next begins.

Comment: @lawlist Thanks! I will struggle with this :)